# получить блоки внутри родителя через this

Tags: javascript

Чтобы получить кнопки prew next внутри каждого wrap, я сделал так, прошелся в цикле по всем wrap, и навесил клик.
Что бы таким образом через this, получить кнопки которые находятся внутри wrap.

Подскажите правильно ли так делать, и если можно сделать как то иначе, то как.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: отформатируйте вопрос: у вас ни одной заглавной буквы, ни одного переноса строки, и ни одной точки (если не считать слово "Спасибо"). Уберите лишние слова. Хорошо оформленный вопрос заметно упрощает его понимание и повышает вероятность хорошего ответа. Вынесите код со скрина в спецблок кода

Answer (score 2):

Зачем так сложно? А если у вас таких элементов миллион? Браузер же не выдержит.
Вешайте один обработчик на общий родитель и все

```html
<html>

<body>

<style>

.wraps {
    width:      100px;
    height:     200px;
    background: red;
}

.wrap {
    margin:     20px;
    background: lime;
}

.wrap div {
    width:      50px;
    height:     25px;
    margin:     10px;
    background: orange;
}

</style>

<div class = 'wraps'>
    <div class = 'wrap obj1'>
        <div class = 'prev'>Prev</div>
        <div class = 'next'>Next</div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'wrap obj2'>
        <div class = 'prev'>Prev</div>
        <div class = 'next'>Next</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

let wraps_obj = document.querySelector('.wraps');

wraps_obj.onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target.className.includes('prev'))
        console.log('Prev button');
        
    if (e.target.className.includes('next'))
        console.log('Next button');     
}

</script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

В итоге код будет занимать всего несколько строчек, но будет понятным и без лишних телодвижений. Кроме того он легко будет переваривать и огромное кол-во отслеживаемых элементов, ведь обработчик только один

Т.е. алгоритм такой:

1. на общий родитель вешается обработчик
2. когда пользователь нажимает на любой элемент внутри родителя, то в функцию обработчика передаётся структура, содержащая в том числе и цель (на что нажал пользователь) `e.target`
3. определяем какие классы у нажатой цели `e.target.className`
4. и если классы содержат отслеживаемый нами класс `e.target.className.includes(отслеживаемый класс)`, то выполняем требуемые действия

конечно, чтобы это работало надо, чтобы отслеживаемый класс находится только у нужных элементов, но это уже легко реализуется

Comment: В двух местах можно поскользнуться: `className.includes('prev')` — туда случайно может попасть другой элемент с каким-нибудь классом `prevent`. Надежнее `classList.contains("prev")`. + `onclick` может быть только один. Можно забыть, что он там был и из другого места его переопределить. `addEventListener("click", function() { ... `

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, на счет первого - да, согласен, так гораздо надежнее, а как убрать второе узкое место? ну кроме того, чтоб не забывать :)

Comment: Через `wraps_obj.addEventListener("click", function(e) { if (e.target...` - можно повесить сколько угодно одинаковых обработчиков)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но вы немного меня не так поняли, мне нужно в переменную занести кнопки prew і next но так как кнопок у меня таких несколько, это уже массив, а мне нужно получить именно две кнопки в родительском блоке, и занести их в переменную. поэтому я таким через this все это сделал.